# I can't detect face with camera2

Tags: java, android, camera2

I can't find information about face detection on preview in android.hardware.Camera2, would anybody help me with a complete example?

I saw some questions with camera2 examples in github but I can't understand them.

I used Camera2 sample from Google: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic.

I set face recognition mode to FULL.

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE, CameraMetadata.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL);
```

Also I checked `STATISTICS_INFO_MAX_FACE_COUNT` and `STATISTICS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FACE_DETECT_MODES`:

```
int max_count = characteristics.get(
CameraCharacteristics.STATISTICS_INFO_MAX_FACE_COUNT);
int modes [] = characteristics.get(
CameraCharacteristics.STATISTICS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FACE_DETECT_MODES); 
 Output: maxCount : 5 , modes : [0, 2]
```

My CaptureCallback:

```
private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

private void process(CaptureResult result) {
            Integer mode = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE);
            Face [] faces = result.get(CaptureResult.STATISTICS_FACES);
            if(faces != null && mode != null)
                Log.e("tag", "faces : " + faces.length + " , mode : " + mode ); 
}

@Override
public void onCaptureProgressed(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request,
                                CaptureResult partialResult) {
    process(partialResult);
}

@Override
public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request,
                               TotalCaptureResult result) {
    process(result);
}     `
```

Output: faces : 0 , mode : 2

```
public static final int STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL = 2;
```

Faces length is constantly 0. Looks like it doesn't recognise a face properly or I missed something.

I know approach with FaceDetector. I just wanted to check how it works with new camera2 Face.

I need to detect face on preview of camera2!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't use **CameraMetadata.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL**, because some devices do not support this type of face detection. Please, can you verify if your device support **STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL**?

If the answer is "NO", please try to use **STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_SIMPLE**

Look at this Samsung Example
https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/camera#techdocs

There is a sample explaining how to use face detection with camera2 API